# Reason to use a global resource to connect to a redis-server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

So, recently I moved all the session-related information in my app to the redis. Everything is running fine and now I am not facing the cookie-related issues (especially from IE).

In doing that, I read some blogs and all of them defined a redis-connector as a global variable in the config like

`$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)`

Now there are a few things that bugging me:

1. Defining a global resource means that I have just a single connection to the redis. Will it create a bottleneck in my system when I have to serve multiple requests?
2. Also when multiple request arrives, will the `Rails` enqueue the requests for the `redis` as the connection is global resource, in case it is already in use?
3. Redis supports multiple instances. Wouldn't creating multiple instances boost the performance?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are no standard connections pools included into Redis gem. If we consider Rails as a single threaded execution model it doesn't sound too problematic.

It might be evil when used in multi-threaded environment (think of background jobs as an example). So connection pooling is a good idea in general.

You can implement it for Redis using [`connection_pool` gem](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool).

Sidekiq also uses this gem for connecting to Redis. It can be seen [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb#L1) and [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/sidekiq.gemspec#L20). Also, sidekiq author is the same person as connection_pool author, https://github.com/mperham.

As to your questions:

1. Multiple requests still don't mean multi-threading, so this approach might work well before you use threads;
2. Rails is not going to play the role of connection pool for your database;
3. It will boost performance (and avoid certain errors) if used in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: so you agree that a connection pool would have a better performance?

Answer (score 0):

1) No it's not a bottleneck, opening TCP for Redis for every query/request cause leak of perfomance.
3) Yes if you have more then one core/thread.

Comment: Can you elaborate the leaks please?

Comment: At first your system needs to open tcp socket, at second connect and login  to redis. And foreach request you should do this over and over. Sounds like a big chunk of useless work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply measure Redis connection number to see there is no new connection instantiated before each Rails request processed. The connection established on rails processor (Unicorn, Puma, Passenger etc) side during application load process.

```
echo info | redis-cli | grep connected_clients
```

Try to run the bash command before and during your application is being run locally.